# Get nested object count of key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am creating a React app and have the following list:

```
const list = [
    {
        id: '1',
        group: 'sports 1',
        sports: [{
            'basketball': [
                {competed: true},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'soccer': [
                {competed: false},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'hockey': [
                {competed: false},
                {won: false}
            ]
        }],
        competedInAll: false
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        group: 'sports 2',
        sports: [{
            'tennis': [
                {competed: false},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'swimming': [
                {competed: false},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'baseball': [
                {competed: false},
                {won: false}
            ]
        }],
        competedInAll: false
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        group: 'sports 3',
        sports: [{
            'volleyball': [
                {competed: true},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'karate': [
                {competed: true},
                {won: false}
            ],
            'surfing': [
                {competed: true},
                {won: false}
            ]
        }],
        competedInAll: false
    }
];
```

I am iterating through the list like so:

```
<ul>
    {list.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
           {item.group}
           <ul>
               {Object.keys(item.sports[0]).map((sport, i) => <li key={i}>{sport}</li>)}
           </ul>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Which will produce the following output:

- sports 1

  - basketball
  - soccer
  - hockey
- sports 2

  - tennis
  - swimming
  - baseball
- sports 3

  - volleyball
  - karate
  - surfing

I am wanting to achieve:

- sports 1 (2 remaining)

  - basketball
  - soccer
  - hockey
- sports 2 (3 remaining)

  - tennis
  - swimming
  - baseball
- sports 3 (compete in all sports)

  - volleyball
  - karate
  - surfing

1. How can I get the total count of `competed` that equal `false` (grouped) in each of the `sports`?
2. How can I set this count to 'competed in all sports' (grouped) when they are all set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getStatus = (item) => {
  let length = Object.values(item.sports[0]).filter(x => !x[0].competed).length;
  /* 
  A more readable version below 
  let sports = item.sports[0];
  let sportDetails = Object.keys(sports);
  let notCompetedSports = sportDetails.filter(sport => sport[0].competed === false);
  let length = notCompletedSports.length'
  */
  return length === 0 ? 'competed in all sports' : length+" remaining"
}
```

```
<ul>
    {list.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
           {item.group} ({getStatus(item)})
           <ul>
               {Object.keys(item.sports[0]).map((sport, i) => <li key={i}>{sport}</li>)}
           </ul>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Dhananjai.  I am getting a `Cannot read property 'sports' of undefined` for `let length = Object.values(item.sports[0]).filter(x => !x[0].competed).length;` error

Comment: yeah, pass the item to the function. Sorry about the typo. updated above.

Comment: is there a way to add an onclick event to update the state to `true` (possibly with hooks)?

Comment: yes, you can add the event on the list item. But please post it as a separate question as it digresses from the original question. The answer should solve the initial question. Would be happy to help with the new question, if you meet with any issues.

Comment: @user1752759, I want you to suggest that you can make your `list` structure more comfortable to use by changing `sports` value to object instead of list like this: `sports : { 'basketball' : { 'completed' : true, 'won' : true }}` by this it would be easy to handle and you can reduce your code line

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
//here I put list in render but you can place in your code as you need
  const list = [
    {
      id: '1',
      group: 'sports 1',
      sports: [{
          'basketball': [
              {competed: true},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'soccer': [
              {competed: false},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'hockey': [
              {competed: false},
              {won: false}
          ]
      }],
      competedInAll: false
    },

    {
      id: '2',
      group: 'sports 2',
      sports: [{
          'tennis': [
              {competed: false},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'swimming': [
              {competed: false},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'baseball': [
              {competed: false},
              {won: false}
          ]
      }],
      competedInAll: false
    },

    {
      id: '3',
      group: 'sports 3',
      sports: [{
          'volleyball': [
              {competed: true},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'karate': [
              {competed: true},
              {won: false}
          ],
          'surfing': [
              {competed: true},
              {won: false}
          ]
      }],
      competedInAll: false
    }
  ];

  let remaining = [] // remaining variable is empty list we will push the number of remaining items which are false in the same sequence as our list item are. 

  //this loop is used to find out the number of completed = false and push in remaining list
  for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    let count = 0;
    for (var key in list[i].sports[0]){
      if(!list[i].sports[0][key][0].competed){
        count = count + 1 
      }
    }
    remaining.push(count);
  }
  //loop end here

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {list.map((item,index) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.group}(remaining: {remaining[index]})
            <ul>
              {Object.keys(item.sports[0]).map((sport, i) => <li key={i}>{sport}</li>)}
            </ul>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Things to note I have added **index** here `list.map((item,index) =>{})` as a extra parameter to recieve in `map()` function and use this index in `{item.group}(remaining: {remaining[index]})`